# No puedo ver el sitio en un servidor apache

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, apache, servidor

tengo un problema para cargar mi sitio web en wordpress a un servidor apache en Windows con unas especificaciones que no conozco.

La ruta para cargar los sitios se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la carpeta *Apache24* hay un directorio llamado htdocs (donde supongo se deben cargar mis sitios). Las especificaciones dicen que debo personalizar los puertos para estos sitios de la siguiente manera:

`www.sitio-uno.com.com -> 8090

www.sitio-dos.com -> 8091

www.sitio-tres.com -> 8092`

Éste servidor no posee archivo host, solo contiene el *httpd-vhost.conf* y el *httpd.conf*

La pregunta es, cual sería la manera correcta de configurar este servidor para que funcione con los 3 sitios como lo esperado? Algún tutorial conocido para este tipo de servidor o especificaciones?

*** Información, este es un servidor virtualizado en Windows.

*** Contiene Apache, php y mySql instalados y funcionando.

*** El acceso está dado por Teamviewer y se configura o cargan los sitios por medio de la transferencia de archivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe añadir las líneas al archivo *C:/WDATA/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf*:

```
Listen 8090
Listen 8091
Listen 8092
```

debajo de `Listen 80`, y luego añadir las directivas correctas al final del archivo *C:/WDATA/Apache24/conf/Extra/httpd-vhost.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/WDATA/Apache24/htdocs/directory1"
  ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8091>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/WDATA/Apache24/htdocs/directory2"
  ServerName domain2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8092>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/WDATA/Apache24/htdocs/directory3"
  ServerName domain3.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Una vez hechos éstos cambios, ve al archivo `hosts` y añade los nuevos dominios. Por último reinicia el servidor apache por medio del comando  abriendo la consola de servicios de Windows. Intenta acceder a las rutas postponiendo :nro-puerto y podrás ver los sitios filtrados para el dominio asignado.

Saludos.